# Place Values of numbers

Tags: number-theory

I have distinct 3-digit numbers that, when multiplied by themselves, produced a number which ended in the same 3-digit number. What are the the distinct 3-digit numbers which have this property?   I have tried using place value concept; but it's not working that way.

Comment: Can you work out an equation form for the three digits? Perhaps the square of three terms?

Comment: Just a tip : 1. The 3-digit number would not have 2,3,7,8 at it's unit place, because It's square also ends up with same 3-digit number, and a perfect Square never ends with any of numbers { 2,3,7,8 }. 2. The square of any 3-digit numbers can have at minimum 5-digits and maximum 6 digits.

Comment: 3. Also, 3-digit number will not have zero at it's first place as it's square would have two zeroes at the end and that will break the constraint.

Comment: 4. From the rest of numbers left {1,4,5,6,9} , only { 1,5,6 } qualify the constraint as their squares will end with unit digit as { 1,5,6 } respectively. So, unit digit must have either of { 1,5,6 }.

Comment: Those Numbers are : 376 & 625. `Sq(376) = 141376` and `Sq(625) = 390625`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very very much C0deDaedalus!   :-D   :-)

Comment: @MathTise Did you got the equation ?

Comment: i didn't get an equation...   but, i tried method of elimination...but your tips made the process very easy!..   is there an equation for this question?

Comment: i got a programming code equation : Select[Range[100,999],Mod[#^2,1000]==#&]

Comment: but not a simple mathematical one...   :-(

Comment: I Thank You all for the solutions.   Greatly appreciated.   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
(100a+10b+c)^2\equiv 200ac+100b^2+20bc+c^2\pmod{1000}
$$
So first of all we must have $c^2\equiv c\pmod{10}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\color{red}{0}^2&=\color{red}{0}\\
\color{red}{1}^2&=\color{red}{1}\\
2^2&=4\\
3^2&=9\\
4^2&=16\\
\color{red}{5}^2&=2\color{red}{5}\\
\color{red}{6}^2&=3\color{red}{6}\\
7^2&=49\\
8^2&=64\\
9^2&=81
\end{align}
$$
So $c\in\{0,1,5,6\}$. Next we must divide into cases.

---

**Suppose $c=0$**:
Then the $10$'s places becomes
$$
[0]_{100}=[10b]_{100}
$$
which is never the case.

---

**Suppose $c=1$**:
Then the $10$'s places becomes
$$
[20b]_{100}=[10b]_{100}
$$
which is never the case.

---

**Suppose $c=5$**: Then the $10$'s places becomes
$$
[100b+20]_{100}=[10b]_{100}
$$
which implies $b=2$. Thus the $100$'s places must satisfy
$$
[1000a+600]_{1000}=[100a]_{1000}
$$
which implies $a=6$. Thus $625$ is a solution.

---

**Suppose $c=6$**: Then the $10$'s places becomes
$$
[120b+30]_{100}=[10b]_{100}\\
\iff\\
[10b+30]_{100}=0
$$
since the $100$ of the $120$ vanishes modulo $100$ and $20b-10b=10b$. This implies $b=7$. Thus the $100$'s places must satisfy
$$
[1200a+5700]_{1000}=[100a]_{1000}\\
\iff\\
[100a+700]_{1000}=0
$$
which implies $a=3$. Thus $376$ is a solution.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH STRING !..this really helps a lot!

Comment: @MathTise: Thank you! That is great to hear. I added the case $c=0$ since it must be considered too for completeness. BTW: I made a computer search for integers $x$ with $x^2$ ending in $x$ more generally. The list is $$1, 5, 6, 25, 76, 376, 625, 9376, 90625, 109376, 890625,...$$ They can also be found in [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+5%2C+6%2C+25%2C+76%2C+376%2C+625%2C+9376%2C+90625%2C+109376%2C+890625&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Also note the fun fact that $$376^2\equiv 376\pmod{1000}$$ and $$625=1001-376\implies 625^2\equiv 1+376^2-2\cdot 376\equiv1001-376\pmod{1000}$$

Comment: One huge such number that my program just generated is $$\scriptsize3953007319108169802938509890062166509580863811000557423423230896109004106619977392256259918212890625$$

Comment: Or even $$\tiny6893714671801375619055462996814764263903953007319108169802938509890062166509580863811000557423423230896109004106619977392256259918212890625$$

Answer (score 1):

If we generalise this to finding $n$-digit numbers such that their square ends in the same $n$ digits as the original number, then we looking for solutions to the equation

$x^2 = x \mod 10^n \Rightarrow x(x-1) = 0 \mod 10^n$

If we exclude the trivial cases $x=0$ and $x=1$, then we have two possibilities:

(1) $x=0 \mod 5^n \text{ and } x=1 \mod 2^n$

(2) $x=0 \mod 2^n \text{ and } x=1 \mod 5^n$

The Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that there is exactly one solution $\mod 10^n$ for each case, although it does not guarantee that both have $n$ digits with no leading zeros. For example, when $n=5$ we have

$90625 = 0 \mod 5^5 \text{ and } 90625 = 1 \mod 2^5$

$9376 = 0 \mod 2^5 \text{ and } 9376 = 1 \mod 5^5$

The symmetry of the remainders mod $10^n$ also explains why the sum of the two solutions is $10^n+1$.